# grok pattern for log event

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm a Logstash newbie and I've looked at numerous examples of grok patterns and I'm still struggling to acheive my goal which is to parse the following `JSON` formatted log event.

```
{
  "@fields": {
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "mdc": {},
    "file": "SearchServiceImpl.java",
    "class": "com.blah.blah.service.impl.SearchServiceImpl",
    "line_number": "767",
    "method": "getUserSavedSearches"
  },
  "@timestamp": "2015-04-24T12:30:37.953+01:00",
  "@message": "username: admin sessionid: 56cR73aBpuIBzRgIElzLUtJJ method_name: getUserSavedSearches",
  "@source_host": "Kens-MacBook.local"
}
```

In particular I'd like to extract the session id and username. 
I'm also hoping I can be pointed to detailed documentation explaining how to use Grok. (I've read the available docs on logstash etc).
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First, your log format is in JSON. So, in your config you can use `json` codec to read the log. Then, use `GROK` to parse the username & session id.

```
input {
    stdin{
        codec => json
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => [
            "@message", "username: %{USERNAME:username} sessionid: %{NOTSPACE:sessionId} method_name: %{WORD:method_name}"
        ]
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

For more detailed document, you can use [this site](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to help you try your grok pattern and [this site](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) for the grok pattern that can use.

Here is the sample output:

```
{
         "@fields" => {
              "level" => "DEBUG",
                "mdc" => {},
               "file" => "SearchServiceImpl.java",
              "class" => "com.blah.blah.service.impl.SearchServiceImpl",
        "line_number" => "767",
             "method" => "getUserSavedSearches"
    },
      "@timestamp" => "2015-04-24T19:30:37.953+08:00",
        "@message" => "username: admin sessionid: 56cR73aBpuIBzRgIElzLUtJJ method_name: getUserSavedSearches",
    "@source_host" => "Kens-MacBook.local",
        "@version" => "1",
            "host" => "BEN_LIM",
        "username" => "admin",
       "sessionId" => "56cR73aBpuIBzRgIElzLUtJJ",
     "method_name" => "getUserSavedSearches"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately this hasn't worked. I tried it in the grok debugger with a 'no match' response. an excerpt from output is attached for reference.

Comment: "@timestamp" => "2015-04-27T08:43:43.839Z",
        "@message" => "username: admin sessionid: -eGqqj0ZsJK-Zgqz4i-utppH method_name: getSavedSearch",
    "@source_host" => "Kays-MacBook.local",
        "@version" => "1",
            "type" => "log4j",
            "host" => "Kenss-MacBook.local",
            "path" => "/opt/jboss-eap-6.3/standalone/log/Service.log",
            "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is because the sessionId have other symbol, you have to NOTSPACE pattern instead of WORD.

Comment: that didn't work but  thanks for your help, you've got the ball rolling .. I've managed to get a valid response with username: %{USERNAME:username} sessionid: %{USERNAME:sessionId} method_name: %{WORD:method} as my sessionid was -eGqqj0ZsJK-Zgqz4i-utppH can you suggest an alternative to using USERNAME for the sessionid ?

Comment: The sessionId in my answer have change to %{NOTSPACE:sessionId}, that's means it will accept character except SPACE. If my answer have help you please kindly marked it as accepted. Thank you.